# Javascript Change table cell background color from second table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if there is any possible way to change the background color of a table cell from choosing a color from second table cell, using javascript only.
If you can tell me how I will be glad. I'm a newbie at this so don't hate me. :)
Thank you for any feedback!

This is how it should look like:

[image]

EDIT: 
My HTML code :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<style>
    table.first {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    table.first td {
        border: solid 2px;
        border-color: black;
        font-size: 3em;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    table.second {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }
    table.second td {
        border: solid 2px;
        border-color: black;
        font-size: 3em;
        padding: 1em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="first">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="second">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="black"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="yellow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="green"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you at least post your table HTML? ..Questions that are effectively just asking for people to write code are typically frowned upon. Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Ok sorry. EDITED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a list of all elements that match the given CSS selector.
2. Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to turn it into an array and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate thru them.
3. Get the `bgcolor` of the clicked `td`and apply it to the all the other table's `td`s.

```js
(function() {
  var color;
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.second td')).forEach(td => {
    td.onclick = function() {
      color = this.getAttribute('bgcolor');
    };
  });
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table.first td')).forEach(td => {
    td.onclick = function() {
      if (color) this.setAttribute('bgcolor', color);
    };
  });
  document.getElementById("clear").onclick = function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table.first td')).forEach(td => {
      td.removeAttribute('bgcolor');
    });
  };
})();
```

```css
table.first {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: inline-block;
}

table.first td {
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}

table.second {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

table.second td {
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button id=clear>Clear</button><br>
<table class="first">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="second">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="black"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="red"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what I wanted to do was if I click a color from right table that choice will save and then if I click on the left table it will paint the whole square from the left table. I hope you understand me, my English is not best.

Comment: @Kokot - Ok, changed my answer.. if that helped you please hit the checkmark to mark the answer as accepted. Please be more specific in the question next time.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! You are my savior. I will do my best next time.

Comment: One last thing if it's not bothering you. Is there any way to clear background colors in the right table? Using button would be the best solution.

Comment: @Kokot - ok... if you have any further questions please post a new question.